# converting address into geocoordinates

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i am trying to convert address into geocoordiantes.when i call this function and print the latlong values system give me the following error.

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=Raiwind Road,Lahore,Pakistan,74.2306&sensor=false) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in C:\wamp\www\temp\yy.php on line 137

the code is given below:kindly resolve it

```
      function getlatlong($address)  
          {   
      $Address = urlencode($address);
      $request_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=".$Address."&sensor=true";
      $xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("url not loading");
       $status = $xml->status;
       if ($status=="OK") {
         $Lat = $xml->result->geometry->location->lat;
        $Lon = $xml->result->geometry->location->lng;
         $LatLng = "$Lat,$Lon";
          }
           return $LatLng;
              }
            $coord=getlatlong($source1);
             print $coord;
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
<?php
  $Address = urlencode($Address);
  $request_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=".$Address."&sensor=true";
  $xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("url not loading");
  $status = $xml->status;
  if ($status=="OK") {
      $Lat = $xml->result->geometry->location->lat;
      $Lon = $xml->result->geometry->location->lng;
      $LatLng = "$Lat,$Lon";
  }
?>
```

References:

- http://www.fcsoftware.co.uk/blog/?p=66
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding